# I can't get my server start on Minecraft 1.16.5 Fabric

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I'm trying to start my fresh server on Fabric 1.16.5 but it's just crashing...
can someone tell me how to fix it?

````
   [12:01:50] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
   [12:01:50] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
   [12:01:50] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
   [12:01:50] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
   [12:01:50] [main/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
   [12:01:50] [Worker-Main-11/INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
   [12:01:51] [Worker-Main-11/INFO]: Loaded 927 advancements
   [12:01:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.16.5
   [12:01:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
   [12:01:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
   [12:01:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
   [12:01:54] [Server console handler/ERROR]: Exception handling console input
   java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
       at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
       at net.minecraft.class_3176$1.run(class_3176.java:95) [intermediary-server.jar:?]
   [12:01:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
   [12:01:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
   [12:02:11] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
   [12:02:11] [Server thread/WARN]: The exception was: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
   [12:02:11] [Server thread/WARN]: Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
   [12:02:11] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
   [12:02:11] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
   [12:02:11] [Server thread/ERROR]: Exception stopping the server
   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
       at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.method_3723(MinecraftServer.java:572) ~[intermediary-server.jar:?]
       at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.method_3782(MinecraftServer.java:599) ~[intermediary-server.jar:?]
       at net.minecraft.class_3176.method_3782(class_3176.java:567) ~[intermediary-server.jar:?]
       at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.method_29741(MinecraftServer.java:707) ~[intermediary-server.jar:?]
       at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.method_29739(MinecraftServer.java:257) ~[intermediary-server.jar:?]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_281]```
````

Comment: `Exception handling console input` - do you supply commands to you server upon startup? Sounds almost like they might be malformed if you do.

Comment: We are sorry, but we are unable to help issues surrounding crashes or errors of modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `[12:02:11] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!`

This is almost always because another server is running on this port. If you're hosting from a linux machine, you can check what processes are running using `top`, and using `pkill java` to kill any java processes

If you're on windows, you can try closing any applications from Task Manager, or as aytimothy pointed out, `taskkill /f /im java.exe` or `taskkill /f /im javaw.exe`

If none of this works, try changing the port to something other than 25565 in `server.properties`. You can try 25566 instead

Comment: didnt worked..but what about the;  java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: i tried changing the port but its showing the same and i didnt find anything in task manager

Comment: First exception is usually the most important. Console input might suggest java isn't reading the console correctly. Did you start the server from a command line or a GUI?

Comment: command line, its working now.. but how i can add more memory to it?
`java -jar fabric-server-launch.jar`

Comment: Set your -Xms and -Xmx flags for minimum and maximum memory. For example `java -jar -Xmx4G server.jar`

Comment: On Windows, this is `taskkill /f /im java.exe` or `taskkill /f /im javaw.exe`.